# Using if-else statment in ASP repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using an item repeater to display a list of forms that are saved in a database. I can grab all forms fine using the DataBinder but each forms are categorized by department and I want to put a header for each department. As of right now I have an object named "Form" which contains an ID, Name, Link, and Department(string). I want to order the forms by department and when a new department appears....place the proper header.

This is what I am trying to make it look like:

[image]

This is what a header looks like:

```
<a name="1"><img src="images/divider_accounting.gif" alt="" height="26px" width="480px"></a>
```

This is how I am getting the items:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItemList" runat="server" 
     OnItemDataBound="rptItemListOnItemDataBound" 
     OnItemCommand="rptItemListOnItemCommand">
   <ItemTemplate>      
       <div class="form col-sm-12">
           <a href="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Link").ToString() %>"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name").ToString() %></a>

           <asp:Panel ID="pnlAdmin" runat="server" Visible="false">
               <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" ResourceKey="EditItem.Text" Visible="false" Enabled="false" />
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" ResourceKey="DeleteItem.Text" Visible="false" Enabled="false" CommandName="Delete" />
           </asp:Panel>
       </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I need to know how to check the department is not the same as the previous and add the correct header image. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two relatively easy ways to make this work.

1. If you are certain the incoming data is always sorted, and linear, you can do this with a few simple tweaks. Make a conditionally visible element in the itemtemplate, and control the visibility in the row data bound event.

   ```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptItemList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptItemListOnItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptItemListOnItemCommand">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Panel runat="server" id="departmentHeaderPanel" Visible="false">
           <a name="1"><img src="images/divider_accounting.gif" alt="" height="26px" width="480px"></a>
       </asp:Panel>  

       <div class="form col-sm-12"> 
           <a href="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Link").ToString() %>"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name").ToString() %></a>  

           <asp:Panel ID="pnlAdmin" runat="server" Visible="false">
               <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" ResourceKey="EditItem.Text" Visible="false" Enabled="false" />
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" ResourceKey="DeleteItem.Text" Visible="false" Enabled="false" CommandName="Delete" />
           </asp:Panel>
       </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
   ```

   ```
   ///Somewhere define the last department as a property or field.
   var lastKnownDepartment = "";

   void ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) {
        var departmentHeaderPanel = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("departmentHeaderPanel");
        var currentForm = (Form)e.Item.DataItem;
        if(currentForm.department <> lastKnownDepartment)
        {
            lastKnownDepartment = currentForm.department;   
            departmentHeaderPanel.Visible = true;
        } else {
            departmentHeaderPanel.Visible = false;
        }
       }
      }
   ```

Total psuedo-code. Did not even check proper syntax...

Or, to be more flexible you can deal with this a better way.

2. Group your forms into departments using linq. Then have nested repeaters, with a normal repeater on the outside, repeating per department. Then databind the inner repeater on the forms in that department. You can again do this in the row data bind event.